# docker nginx stream balancer 404

Tags: nginx, docker, load-balancing

I have docker and nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu 16.04)

```
my nginx.conf

user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

include /etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/*;


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}
```

this is default nginx.conf, and I added  **include /etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/*;**

tcpconf.d contains 1 file:

```
stream {
    upstream docker{
        server localhost:8182;
        server localhost:8183;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass docker;
    }
}
```

So basically i have glassfish 4 server on docker, and when i start container on port 8182 i want to nginx balance request to port 8183(if 8182 not responding) and in reverse order.

And this is works perfectly, except one thing, when i start container, glassfish server is starting and web application on this server is starting too. Glassfish starts after 1-5 seconds and web application after 30 sec - 1 min, so when glassfish is up(for example on port 8182) nginx send request to this port and i getting 404, because glassfish is up, but web application is not, in this case I want to be redirected on port 8183 because 404 is not what i want to see)

so my question is how to tell nginx to not showing me 404 and try to request another port?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you are using the stream module for this? If it is a regular http server NGINX is proxying to then use regular http{} and proxy_next_upstream to define behavior on 404 error:

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_next_upstream

Comment: Reason why i using stream is because this is first method which i found in google, and which is worked, i will try http, thank you